# JQuery, como se puede meter un código html y luego recuperarlo entero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un jquery que guarda todos los tr.test, que es de una tabla. Y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
localStorage.setItem("libro", JSON.parse($("tr.test").html()));
```

Luego al cargar la pagina nuevamente lo hago de esta forma:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("libro")!=undefined){
    $(localStorage.getItem("libro")).appendTo($(".tabla").children())
  }
```

Pero no me funciona, ya que no saca nada y no se si es porque lo guarda con muchos " y no se como arreglar.

Comment: Qué error te sale en la consola?

Comment: has intentado imrprmir por consola que hay guardado en el localStorage??}

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si sale, sale como de esta forma: " <tr calss="test"><tr> <tr calss="test"><tr> <tr calss="test"><tr> <tr calss="test"><tr>" Yo creo que esta fallando por los "

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara No me sale ninguno

Comment: y si primero agregas lo que esta en localStorage a una variable y despues la insertas???

Comment: y si intentas esto:


`if(localStorage.getItem("libro")!=undefined){
    let libro = localStorage.getItem("libro");
    $(".tabla").append(libro);
}`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Ahora hago el test